# How to access other network files using notepad++ file explorer?

Tags: notepad++

It is not a programming question but I hope you can help me with this. I am editing a code in other PC network by accessing the network IP address. And what I did is I need to hit CTRL+O to prompt an explorer and to that I can directly go to the file I need to modify. Is there a way that the remote files will be visible to the explorer?

For example I am accessing the file to this IP

\10.0.0.180\xampp

In notepad++, is there a plugin that can display the network files to the explorer?

Comment: I use the UNC from the Windows Open/Save dialogs
In the Dialog's address bar, Type in the "share", press Enter to navigate to the list of folders and then in folder list select your folder. Type a file name in the "file name" bar
The "share" you typed in should be "remembered" the next time you do this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you mean, but when you hit CTRL + o you can type in:

> \\10.0.0.180\xampp

and press enter. That will open up that file share and let you browse the files in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party, but I just managed to solve this issue at work, and there doesn't seem to be an answer already, so here it is.

The network drives are mapped to your current Windows user. However, Notepad++ can launch as administrator by default.

If you start Notepad++ as an admin, meaning a different user than your current logged in user, the mapping of the network drives may be different, and therefore N++ is unable to locate files because the drive simply doesn't exist for the admin user.

So either add the network drive to the admin user, or, better solution, uncheck "launch as administrator" in notepad++.exe's contextual menu (right click on notepadd++.exe in its installation folder, click "properties", select the "compatibility tab", and uncheck "launch as administrator").

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Not Supported

I'm using NPP 7.8.7 (64-bit) in Windows 10. I don't use the NPP Explorer plugin anymore, largely because of this. Most of my work is done on many shared folders.

I've done a lot of research (Google), and have come to the conclusion that the "Explorer" plugin in Notepad++ does not support UNC paths (for shared folders, etc.)

From my own experience, using the "Folder of Current File" button in Explorer plugin does nothing.

In the NPP Explorer, Browse to the Windows Desktop. The plugin shows local shortcuts to local folders, but won't show a shortcut to a UNC path.

Using the NPP "Favorites" plugin, click the "New LInk..." button and create a link for a UNC. Then click on the new link. The Explorer plugin will open to the previous view; it won't go to the linked UNC.

### Map a Network Drive

You can map it to a drive, although that's not always very practical for some users who want to make Links in the Favorites plugin for many UNCs, and it's harder to remember where they go with just a letter.

Below are some workarounds, however, there are still use cases where I miss being able to use the NPP Explorer plugin.

### NPP Favorites - [Web]

In NPP Favorites plugin, Don't create the link under [Folders] because those are passed to NPP Explorer. Instead, create the link under [Web]. Those will be passed to MS Windows, which will open the default program for the link. A link to http, etc., will open in a browser, but a link to a UNC will be opened in MS Windows Explorer.

You can also use [Files] for a UNC that includes the filename, which will be passed directly to the Notepad++ editor.

### MS Windows dialog

As you already know, browsing from any MS Windows dialog or MS Windows Explorer works (Ctrl+O, File > Open Containing Folder, etc.), and In Windows 10, the "Quick Access" in file Explorer works fine for Favorites.